# RequestedScope in Quartz Job

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler, cdi

Well, i'm trying to use RequestedScoped beans inside a Quartz Job, see:

```
public class JobRoboFtp implements Job {

    @Inject
    private AcervoVideoService acervoVideoService;

    @Inject
    private ConfiguracaoService configuracaoService;

    @Inject
    private FtpManager ftpManager;
```

But i got always:

```
No active contexts for scope type javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped
```

Well, If i change this Services to @Dependent scope everything works but i would like to use RequestedScope. There is any way ?

Answer (score 2):

Since you didn't say much about versions, I am going to assume some of the latest versions of Weld 2.x (or even 3.x) - then there is a way. I also assume you are talking about SE environment, as otherwise request scope would auto-activate during requests.

If we are talking CDI 1.2 (Weld 2.x) then you need to add explicit dependency on Weld API and make use of it. The dependency is `org.jboss.weld:weld-api` and the functionality you are looking for is [`@ActivateRequestContext` interceptor binding](https://github.com/weld/api/blob/2.4.Final/weld/src/main/java/org/jboss/weld/context/activator/ActivateRequestContext.java). If you are looking for a link to Weld docs, its [here](http://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/latest/en-US/html_single/#_request_context) - note that this was added in Weld 2.4!

The principle is simple - it intercepts method calls and activated context when entering the method, then destroys it when you exit the method.

```
@ActivateRequestContext
public void myMethod() {
  // any content in here will have request context ACTIVE
  doAwesomeThings();
}
```

If we are talking about CDI 2.0/Weld 3.x - then the very same approach was adapted by CDI (Weld version works there as well). You can read about it [here](http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/2.0/cdi-spec.html#activating_builtin_contexts).